# Unable to Remove Images with the Media Module

Tags: media

While working with the Media Module I have noticed that I am unable to remove images/pdfs while under **Content** >> **Media Tab**. I first encountered this problem when faced with having to remove duplicate images/pdfs from Drupal. Once removed, the image/pdf still remains with a preview broken icon displaying. On the second attempt in removing the broken image an error message displays. See screen captures below:

[image]

**System Information:**

•   Drupal 7

•   Bartik 7.12

Comment: You have content somewhere in the system that's referencing the media item you're trying to delete...if you remove the references from those content items you'll be able to remove the image from the media gallery

Comment: I tried that and I am still encountering the same conflict.